# Freeradius 3.0 doesn't send any data through mysql (radacct table empty)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, freeradius, radius

I have deployed a freeradius server version 3.0 with MySQL in Ubuntu (20.04).
There are the respective versions of the radius and MySQL:

```
root@server:/etc/freeradius/3.0# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
root@server:/etc/freeradius/3.0# freeradius -v
radiusd: FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.20, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Jan 25 2020 at 06:11:13
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.20
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
```

My situation is: from a mobile phone I need to connect to an access point and authenticate to that WLAN network (802.11i-WPA-802.1x) using a username and password specified in the radius database.

I would like to limit the number of concurrent logins per user (demouser in this case) to 1 because i only have one unique user. I have spent a lot of time searching the forums and documentation, but can't find anything to figure it.

This is the [output](https://justpaste.it/4s3lh) of freeradius in debug mode.

I have several doubts about what would be the best way to create the user in the database.
At the moment it is configured in a basic way, that is to say I have specified in the radcheck table the user and in the nas table my client (the access point):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM nas;
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+---------------+
| id | nasname     | shortname | type  | ports | secret   | server | community | description   |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | 172.20.1.20 | AP_1      | other |  NULL | 12345678 | NULL   | NULL      | Client Radius |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> SELECT * FROM radcheck; SELECT * FROM radgroupcheck; SELECT * FROM radgroupreply; SELECT * FROM radusergroup;
+----+----------+--------------------+----+----------+
| id | username | attribute          | op | value    |
+----+----------+--------------------+----+----------+
|  1 | demouser | Cleartext-Password | := | demopass |
+----+----------+--------------------+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----+------------+------------------+----+-------+
| id | groupname  | attribute        | op | value |
+----+------------+------------------+----+-------+
|  1 | demo_group | Simultaneous-Use | := | 1     |
+----+------------+------------------+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----+------------+--------------------+----+---------------------+
| id | groupname  | attribute          | op | value               |
+----+------------+--------------------+----+---------------------+
|  1 | demo_group | Service-Type       | := | Framed-User         |
|  2 | demo_group | Framed-Protocol    | := | PPP                 |
|  3 | demo_group | Framed-Compression | := | Van-Jacobsen-TCP-IP |
+----+------------+--------------------+----+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----+----------+------------+----------+
| id | username | groupname  | priority |
+----+----------+------------+----------+
|  1 | demouser | demo_group |        0 |
+----+----------+------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if I see the logs file the authentications makes successfull:

- This is the output of `/var/log/freeradius/sqllog.sql`

  `INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate) VALUES ( 'demouser', '', 'Access-Accept', '2021-04-27 09:04:19');`
- This is the other output of `/var/radacct/172.20.1.20/auth-detail....`

  ```
  Tue Apr 27 09:37:46 2021
  Packet-Type = Access-Request
  User-Name = "demouser"
  Service-Type = Framed-User
  NAS-IP-Address = 172.20.1.20
  NAS-Port = 1
  NAS-Port-Id = "1"
  State = 0x7eea823f76e09b79e9fd1595f5ebf47a
  Called-Station-Id = "EC-E5-55-FF-FB-34:HIRSCHMANN_C"
  NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
  WLAN-RF-Band = 2
  WLAN-Pairwise-Cipher = 1027076
  WLAN-Group-Cipher = 1027076
  WLAN-AKM-Suite = 1027073
  Calling-Station-Id = "78-B8-D6-32-9A-32"
  Connect-Info = "CONNECT 72 Mbps 802.11g/n"
  NAS-Identifier = "AP_1"
  Framed-MTU = 1500
  EAP-Message = 0x020a002e190017030300230000000000000004425534a3fe3939c900e3f3f672628ae179e4a05c48c1964a31dba1
  Message-Authenticator = 0xd87613c17b7b62950f6613cbca20e109
  Event-Timestamp = "Apr 27 2021 09:37:46 CEST"
  Timestamp = 1619509066
  ```

And if I perform a select from the *radpostauth* table I also see that the user has been successfully authenticated.

```
mysql> select * from radpostauth;
+----+----------+------+---------------+---------------------+
| id | username | pass | reply         | authdate            |
+----+----------+------+---------------+---------------------+
| 55 | demouser |      | Access-Accept | 2021-04-27 09:04:19 |
| 56 | demouser |      | Access-Accept | 2021-04-27 09:04:19 |
+----+----------+------+---------------+---------------------+
```

The problem is that in the radacct table no data is stored, when I perform a select it appears empty, I have created another table which is radaacct2 with the same structure and specified in the mysql configuration file but no data is inserted either.

From what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) Radius stores accounting data in radacct table. I read this [document](https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Data-Usage-Reporting)

If no data is stored, the following query will not be executed correctly. `/etc/freeradius/3.0/main/mysql/queries.conf` :

```
#######################################################################
# Simultaneous Use Checking Queries
#######################################################################
# simul_count_query     - query for the number of current connections
#                       - If this is not defined, no simultaneous use checking
#                       - will be performed by this module instance

simul_count_query = "\
        SELECT COUNT(*) \
        FROM ${acct_table1} \
        WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' \
        AND acctstoptime IS NULL"
```

In short, I need to control the simultaneous login of a specific user and the cause of not working correctly I think it is due to not inserting data into the mysql table. I am probably wrong because I am new to this, I ask please that in the case that it is so, someone provide me with information on how to fix this problem or specify me really what is the error in question.

I have been working on this for weeks and it is the last thing I need to configure but I can't figure it out.

If any more configuration files are needed please let me know and I will attach them.

Help please

PD: as extra information I have to add that I have followed the configuration steps on this [page](https://www.vpsserver.com/community/tutorials/10/setup-and-configuration-of-freeradius-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04-64bit/) and it still does not work.

Thanks